# JSON Array parsing to Swift Codeable

Tags: json, swift, parsing

How would I parse this JSON into Codeable struct. I am also using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) library to make request

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Delivery"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dine-out"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Nightlife"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now my Codeable struct looks like below:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {

    struct Category: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }

    var categories: Category
}
```

I am gettig an error saying **Expected to decode Array but found a Dictionary instead.**

**UPDATE**

```swift
provider.request(.categories) { (result) in
//            guard let self = self else { return }

            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                let data = response.data
                //let json = try? JSON(data: data)
                // swiftlint:disable:next force_try
                let test = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Respo].self, from: data)
                print(test)
//                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: More than 50 search results for `[swift] "Expected to decode Array but found a Dictionary instead."` and nothing helped?

Comment: @MartinR trust me nothing did. I could send you my chrome history

Comment: @MartinR I have updated my question...now it shows how I decode JSON...could you please take a look.

Comment: But look at your json and your code, you _do not_ have an array at the top level.

Comment: This cannot be the real code because there is no `struct Respo` in your code. In any case,  `decode([Respo].self, from: data)` expects an *array* and your JSON (with the curly braces) is a *dictionary.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

In you model `Response`, `categories` is of type `Category`. But as per your JSON response, `categories` is an *array of dictionary*. That's the reason it is giving **Expected to decode Array but found a Dictionary instead**

**Solution:**

`categories` in Response model must be of type `[[String:Category]]` instead.

So, The models for parsing the above data should be,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let categories: [[String:Category]]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

**Edit:**

Parse it like,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Giving same error. I have updated my question which shows how I am decoding JSON.

Comment: @UtsavDave I've edited the question with parsing code.